# AngularJs nested ngRepeat with horizontal paging - 4 divs filled with 4 objects on each page stacked 2 x 2

Tags: angularjs, pagination, css-float, angularjs-ng-repeat, horizontal-scrolling

I need to use nested ngRepeat this to get 4 objects per page. The items are a standard height and width but the number of items is dynamic. I would like them to stack up 2 high by 2 wide per page with utilizing UI-Bootstrap-Angular Pagination Component... I have tried some splitting directives but nothing gets the results I am seeking. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle of what you have tried?

Comment: I will get one setup...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/stobywan/w5YD3/

Comment: I need to get the items in each section 2x4 per page with item one on top of item two and item 3 next to item 1 and then item 4 next to item 2 and then horizontally paged .... I hope this is clear enough...

Comment: Any chance you ever figured this out @StobyWan?